# Can I make my Hadoop reducer quicker?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm newbie to Hadoop, and just trying the wordcount example.
I just build a single node referring to http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

I upload a very simple text with few words to HDFS, and run the wordcount.jar.

Somehow it takes very very long time for reducer to process. I know it is the I/O bottleneck, but are there any ways I can set some parameters and make it faster? (lol, the reduce process is still 0%, almost 20 minutes)

```
13/06/04 15:53:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop WordCount example stuck at map 100% reduce 0%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165549/hadoop-wordcount-example-stuck-at-map-100-reduce-0)

Comment: Shameless self-plug: http://whiteycode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/hadoop-local-map-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Hadoop have some issues, and the MR could not run correctly.

Please check:

1. Whether your Hadoop work correctly by access `http://localhost:50030`, which is the JobTracker WebUI of your hadoop
2. Look into  the log files on your $HADOOP_HOME/logs/, especially the `*jobtracker*.log`, and `*tasktracker*.log`.

Usually, if it is your first time testing Hadoop. Please check this link: [Hadoop WordCount example stuck at map 100% reduce 0%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165549/hadoop-wordcount-example-stuck-at-map-100-reduce-0)

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem is, when I format the namenode, the host URL is not 127.0.0.1 (weird). That caused the Connection problem. SO I edited the /etc/hosts file to change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify some Hadoop settings like increasing the number of Reduce tasks, you can use the "-D" option:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount -D mapred.reduce.tasks=8 /user/hduser/temp-data /user/hduser/temp-data-output
```

Moreover with HDFS you cannot force number of map tasks `mapred.map.tasks` but you can specify `mapred.reduce.tasks` as explained in this [link](http://markmail.org/message/k32nrcb2ncsq67ef?q=mapred.map.tasks%20)