# HDInsight word count map reduce program stuck at mapper 100% and reducer 0%

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Hadoop and I have a very similar problem as [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165549/hadoop-wordcount-example-stuck-at-map-100-reduce-0). Only thing is OP runs hadoop on linux where as I am  running it on Windows.

I have installed Hadoop Azure HDInsight Emulator on my local machine. When I run a simple  word count program. Mapper jobs runs perfectly 100% but Reduce job gets stuck at 0%.

[image]

I tried debugging it as suggested by Chris (In response to [this que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165549/hadoop-wordcount-example-stuck-at-map-100-reduce-0)) and found the problem with hostname on which reducer jobs run (which was the exact problem as of OP)

[image]

Reduce is not running on `localhost` instead it runs on some hostname `192.168.17.213` which is not getting resolved and reducer can not progress from there.

These are error logs

```
copy failed: attempt_201402111921_0017_m_000000_0 from 192.168.17.213
2014-02-12 01:51:53,073 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask:     
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

OP got that issue resolved by chaning `\etc\hosts` file setting to localhost.

But that seems to be a linux config.. How do I set my hostname to localhost in my Hadoop Azure HDInsight Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article showing you how to run the word counting MapReduce program on HDInsight emulator.  The article is Get started with HDInsight emulator located at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-get-started-emulator/.

Comment: This article shows running map count using java map reduce executable (.jar files).. where as I am using .NET hadoop API to execute my program. I am pretty much sure that my program is fine the only thing is my reducer run on some hostname other then localhost which It can not resolve. There must be some configuration somewhere in Emulator to set it to localhost that I want to know.